# PublishSubject subscriber is not receiving events

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a class `ViewModel` that exposes a `PublishSubject` binder.

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel {

    private PublishSubject<ActionsEvent> binder = PublishSubject.create();
    private Service service = createService();

    @Override
    public Observable<ActionsEvent> getBinder() {
        return binder.doOnSubscribe(initialize());
    }

    private Action0 initialize() {
        return new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                service.getActions().subscribe(new Action1<Action>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Action action) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "So far, so good");
                        binder.onNext(new ActionFetchedEvent(action));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And in the Activity, it subscribe an action to be executed when each event is fetched.

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        //More code
        viewModel.getBinder().subscribe(new Action1<ActionsEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void call(ActionsEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "This is not printed!!");
                paintActionInUserInterface(event.getAction());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public interface ActionsService {
    @GET("/actions")
    Observable<Action> getActions(); //Performs an HTTP request with Retrofit
}
```

**ActionFetchedEvent**

```
public class ActionFetchedEvent implements ActionsEvent {

    private Action action;

    //getters and setters

}
```

But subscriber doesn't receive the event. Why?

Comment: Why do you need a Subject at all? you can just subscribe the `Observable` returned by your service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you do not create an Subject with .create() factory-method, and onSubscribe will be called before the callback of your subscription, so you will subscribe too late and miss the element. You could use a BahaviourSubject, which will replay the last element, if you subscribe.

Could you please tell us what you want to achieve, because I think you could compose the observables in a way better way, than subscribing and posting onNext onto the subject.

Please have a look at my example. I use RxJava2 as environment.

```
public class ViewModelTest {
    class ActionsEvent {
    }

    class ActionFetchedEvent extends ActionsEvent {
        public ActionFetchedEvent(ActionsEvent actionEvent) {

        }
    }

    interface Service {
        public Observable<ActionsEvent> getActions();
    }

    class MyViewModel {
        private BehaviorSubject<ActionsEvent> binder;

        private Service service;

        public MyViewModel(Service service) {
            this.service = service;
            this.binder = BehaviorSubject.create();
        }

        public Observable<ActionsEvent> getBinder() {
            return binder.doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                service.getActions().subscribe(action -> {
                            binder.onNext(new ActionFetchedEvent(action));
                        }
                );
            });
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        Service mock = mock(Service.class);

        MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(mock);

        when(mock.getActions()).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            return Observable.just(new ActionsEvent());
        });

        TestObserver<ActionsEvent> test = viewModel.getBinder().test();

        test.assertValueCount(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it and it works, but when I have 2 events, subscriber only receives the last one. Should I use ReplaySubject instead? I just want to emit one event per action retrieved from service (http request). The subscriber paints each action (contained in the event) in UI.

Comment: Please update your question with a detailed explantation what getActions does and what you are trying to achieve. I can not understand properly what is happening. Please also provide information about how many items getActions would send and what subscribers of getBinder should receive.

Comment: Edited. I hope you understand and thanks for your time.

Comment: So, is this what you are trying to achieve: You have a View which will subscribe to the ViewModel. Upon subscription a http request will be triggered, which will return 1 to multiple elements via getActions and then complete. The Action(s) will be transformed to ActionEvent(s). As they come in the subscription, they will be rendered in the View. If some other subscriber comes in late, should it also get all values, which have been put through the pipeline?